# WPF Table Multiple Row Header

Tags: wpf-controls, row, grouping, flowdocument, documentviewer

How can i achieve this multiple row header in WPF table?

Example:

```
ID     Name         Age      Gender
       City         Phone 1   
       Address 1    Phone 2
       Address 2
------------------------------------
1      Justin       30        M
       L.A.         1000000
       St.Add 1     2000000
       St.Add 2
2      Monica       25        F
       Salt Lake    5000000
       St.Add 8     6000000
       St.Add 9
```

Table is placed in a flow document and which will be shown via WPF Document Viewer. Thank you.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst I tried to use this http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/. Modified the SimpleReport template as above but I don't know how to group them. Any ideas please?